# Can i create local test environment for integrating google drive and my web app

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I want to open certain files in google drive with my webbapp. From what i know i need to publish my web app to G suit marketplace and set up Drive UI integration, this is straight forward i think.

Is there a way to set up testing environment without going through the process of publishing an app to G suit marketplace? Documentation gives me some idea what i need to do :

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open

but some real requests will help to develop.

Comment: Have you checked [this Marketplace FAQ](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/faq#how_do_i_make_my_application_end-user_installable_in_the_marketplace) if it is applicable to your question?

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific problem is, but as a hint, I do my local testing using `localtest.example.com`. My dev machines all resolve `localhost.example.com` to 127.0.0.1. You'll need to install a tsl cert to keep Chrome happy. Use https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert